# Create a custom form for posts - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website with twentyseventeen theme.

I wish a form posts like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVvOW.png) to upload posts.

Searching on google , I found https://wordpress.org/plugins/form-to-post/ but didn't help me !

How can I do that ?

I think that I shoud install a plugin and after customize it, but I don't know ...

Please give me some ideas.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hey, heads up- your question is going to get voted down quite a bit, you should review the guidelines and rephrase it!What do you mean, the light blue background with the dark blue border.

Answer (score 1):

To create, manage and embed charts and graphs in your wordpress post you're looking for [Visualizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer/) plugin.

To create a custom fields , you should use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin , which will help to register and manage new custom fields types.

If you could combine those two plugins, i'm pretty sure you'll be able create posts as you mentioned above.

Comment: I want a form post with these fields http://imgur.com/a/jKMQ2 , not a custom post type ! :)